# Code Sample on using Smart Target with DD4T

Tags: dd4t, smarttarget

Do we have any code sample on using smart target with DD4T? What are the limitations we have with using Fredhopper Query service with DD4T?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are trying to do? Is there a reason not to use the SmartTarget controls?

Comment: @PeterKjaer, DD4T is MVC.NET which isn't compatible with ASPX Controls as far as I understand.

Comment: See http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3635/what-are-the-options-for-integrating-smarttarget-if-using-mvc-or-dd4t from John Winter

Comment: We decided to use DD4T(Java) and have requirement to integrate smart target with the DD4T. Since I heard that it can be possible but that is possible with different ways, i.e. Either using FAS query web service but that have there own limitations like region filter passing, max items to be return, link resolving. or use REL tag which I am not sure how we can implement that. So that's why I am looking for samples.